# jQuery to expand content area DIVs one by one

Tags: jquery

This site [here](http://postevand.com/), has a selection of hyperlinks that expand content areas. One by one, using slide up and down.

I have this code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w0nck144/2/), on a jsFiddle, but it mesbehaves terribly. It does not select the individual div corresponding to the `<a>` tag.

Can anyone guide me on achieveing this desried effect?

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.show').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.targ').eq(index).slideDown();
        jQuery('.targ').not(newTarget).slideUp();

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="show" target="1">NEWS</a>
<div id="div1" class="targ">Text 1</div>


<a class="show" target="2">ABOUT</a>
<div id="div2" class="targ">Text 2</div>


<a class="show" target="3">MAP</a>
<div id="div3" class="targ">Text 3 </div>


<a class="show" target="4">BUY</a>
<div id="div4" class="targ">Text 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were having is a result of your incorrect use of `index()`; the `index()` of the clicked `<a>` element is the index of that element including its sibling `<a>` and `<div>` elements; therefore the index of the last `<a>` is `6`, and the last `<div>` element in the collection of `<div>` elements is `3`.

Therefore, logically, correcting the use of `index()` to find the index of the clicked `<a>` from among its `<a>` siblings will correct the problem:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.show').click(function() {

    // here we find the index of the clicked <a> from
    // among its <a> siblings, discarding the <div>
    // elements:
    var index = $(this).index('a'),
      newTarget = jQuery('.targ').eq(index).slideDown();
    jQuery('.targ').not(newTarget).slideUp();

  });
});
```

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.show').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('a'),
      newTarget = jQuery('.targ').eq(index).slideDown();
    jQuery('.targ').not(newTarget).slideUp();

  });
});
```

```css
a,
div {
  display: block;
}

a+div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show" target="1">NEWS</a>
<div id="div1" class="targ">Text 1</div>


<a class="show" target="2">ABOUT</a>
<div id="div2" class="targ">Text 2</div>


<a class="show" target="3">MAP</a>
<div id="div3" class="targ">Text 3 </div>


<a class="show" target="4">BUY</a>
<div id="div4" class="targ">Text 4</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/57LkLkxq/).

A slightly easier, non index-related approach, is the following:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.show').click(function() {

    // retrieve the number held in the (non-valid) 'target'
    // attribute:
    var targetNumber = $(this).attr('target');

    // concatenate that number with the 'div' prefix (as an
    // id-selector) and use the resulting id to select the
    // element:
    $('#div' + targetNumber)
      // use slideDown() to show that element:
      .slideDown()
      // use the siblings() method to select the
      // siblings matching the supplied selector:
      .siblings('div.targ')
      // and hide those elements, using the
      // slideUp() method:
      .slideUp();
  });
});
```

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.show').click(function() {
    var targetNumber = $(this).attr('target');
    $('#div' + targetNumber).slideDown().siblings('div.targ').slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
a,
div {
  display: block;
}

a+div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="show" target="1">NEWS</a>
<div id="div1" class="targ">Text 1</div>


<a class="show" target="2">ABOUT</a>
<div id="div2" class="targ">Text 2</div>


<a class="show" target="3">MAP</a>
<div id="div3" class="targ">Text 3 </div>


<a class="show" target="4">BUY</a>
<div id="div4" class="targ">Text 4</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/57LkLkxq/1/).

It's also worth noting that, if you use the HTML elements properly, you can take advantage of CSS to provide the functionality you require, with one proviso. So, replacing the `target` attribute with the `href` attribute and providing the `id` of the target element as the `href` attribute-value, allows use of the `:target` pseudo-class to apply to the element you want to show:

```css
a,
div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a+div {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.4s linear;
}

div:target {
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<a class="show" href="#div1">NEWS</a>
<div id="div1" class="targ">Text 1</div>


<a class="show" href="#div2">ABOUT</a>
<div id="div2" class="targ">Text 2</div>


<a class="show" href="#div3">MAP</a>
<div id="div3" class="targ">Text 3 </div>


<a class="show" href="#div4">BUY</a>
<div id="div4" class="targ">Text 4</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/57LkLkxq/2/).

The only problem with this approach is that while we animate the `height` we must provide a relevant unit of length for the `height` property to animate to; whereas jQuery's `slideUp()`, `slideDown()` and `slideToggle()` methods all animate the height to the appropriate height for the content of the element that's being hidden, shown or toggled. But, depending on the nature of your content this may, or may not, be a deal-breaker.

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:target` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).
  - [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).
  - [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Comment: Works like a dream. Thank you David! :-)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed! Please, though, do check out the updates to the answer :)

Comment: Throw me your brain if you want, I'll happily swap :-)